# Marklogic : Query response time is very high

Tags: marklogic

I have around 15000 records in xml format in a uri, say:"`documents/products/specs/*.xml`".
Each xml is of around 25 Kilo Bytes in size. I connected to this marklogic server uisng a remote Apache Tomcat Server that has a `XCC client` (Java), which tries to execute a `AdHocQuery` which resembles something like this:

```
let $a := cts:uri-match('documents/products/specs/*.xml')
          for $xml in $a
          return fn:doc($a)
```

(for loop is implemented in java).

This works fine. But for records with larger count, say for 15000 record, it takes 60 minutes, when all the server and internet speed are very good. (Total size of all document in the uri will be around 20 MB which should not take more than 20 Minutes).

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: 15,000 * 25 = 375,000 not 20-MB.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cts:search(
    fn:doc(),
    cts:document-query(
        cts:uri-match('documents/products/specs/*.xml')
    ), "unfiltered"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is requesting the full body of ALL documents.   This is not a typical query, rather it is a DB dump.  The query you show will buffer up all this data, then send it through tomcat which again buffers up all the data and then send it to you.
This is a large dataset to be sending in one request.

What is the intent of your query ? If you want to get all documents you should either dump them out using a program like mlcp or fetch them in smaller batches by first collecting the URI's then fetching the documents.  This can be speeded up substantially by doing the document fetching in parallel.   You can see examples of Java source in xmlsh that shows how to fetch documents in XCC in parallel

```
http://xmlsh.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xmlsh/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/get.java?revision=792&view=markup
```

My guess (correct me if I am wrong) is you are just experimenting and dont actually need all the docs.  In which case a more realistic query should be tried.

Comment: the requirement is to make ms-excel compatible csv files representing all files in the directory.

Comment: So ask that question: "how do I best make an ms-excel compatible csv file representing all documents in a MarkLogic directory?"

Comment: @mblakele : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016876/ms-excel-compatible-csv-file-representing-all-documents-in-a-marklogic-directory

Comment: do you want the document names or the content to be placed in the csv?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the query is taking so long is because the Marklogic server is reading form the disk, for most of those files. Unless you have a really big tree-cache size. What you need to do is lower the scope of your query. Maybe add some indexes to the files.

All that said if all you want to do is ETL that data out then you might want to batch the request.